# AngularJS 405(Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http, google-app-engine

Working with AngularJS project with PHP as backend(slimphp). The problem i have is that all my GET requests works but not POST

**This is my AngularJS code:**

```
function getContainer() {
            $http.post("/api/favorite")
                .then(function (response) {
                   console.log(response);
                })
        }
```

**This is my PHP-route code: (removed the real function, just for test)**

```
$app->post('/api/favorite', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    echo "test";
});
```

**This is my error on chrome developer console:**
[image]

**Also inside the Server Log i can see this: (WHY does it say GET not POST?)**

> INFO     2017-11-27 15:42:45,796 module.py:821] api: "GET
>   /api/favorite HTTP/1.1" 405 556

Comment: It seems the verb is correct, as witnessed by your dev console. It’s odd that the server logs a `GET` though. Have you tried hitting endpoint with Postman?

Comment: It works by using Postman now. But not from the Client-side with this AngularJS code. hmmm?

Comment: If it works with Postman now, are you perhaps getting a CORS issue with Angular, or is it the same `405`?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @JorgeValle, yes i figured it out. It is a bug in Google App Engine dev_appserver.py and Windows envoirment. Deploying it to production worked and i don't get 405-error. I only get this error on Localhost. If it were CORS problems i would get an error in debugg console but i didn't. so i suspected an envoirment bug on windows with dev_appserver.py that GAE uses